# Find folder name from a specific location

Tags: command

How can I find a folder from a specific location using command prompt.

eg:- I want to search files from desktop and there are around 10 files that contains the name starting from A and i want locations of all such file with file name.

I know it can be done using find commnad but I am unable to write the correct code for it.

Thanks for the help

Comment: (1) Not programming related (2) When you ask on SuperUser, please state the OS. `command` is not a usable tag.

Answer (score 0):

you can find all files from a directory and sub directories that start with 'a' using this:

```
dir  /b /s a*.*
```